# QGIS how to activate the checkboxes of the constractions in the attribute form by Python code and add expressions?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, python-3

[image]

I tried using this type of line for the edit form , but its only for versions 2.8 but I don't know how is for new version 3.0 including "Enforce not null constraint".

```
formConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
formConfig.setNotNull( idx, True )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi CVbuzon this seems to work using the python window on QGIS 3.10:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
fields = layer.fields()
idx = fields.indexFromName('yourfield')
layer.setFieldConstraint(idx, QgsFieldConstraints.ConstraintNotNull)
```

Hope it helps!